# Recommended jsreport settings for .NET Core client

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, jsreport

I have a couple of projects on IIS that utilize jsreport. It works great, except the documentation for setting up the node.js server are limited. I followed the steps shown here: https://jsreport.net/learn/windows and then added the below in my startup on both projects:

```cs
services.AddJsReport(new ReportingService("http://localhost:5488"));
```

It's working fine but I'd like to optimize this as much as possible. What are the recommended configuration settings when running the configure command?

Comment: The `jsreport configure` command should prepare a config file with good defaults for most of the loads. Any particular problems with defaults?

Comment: I'm mainly curious about reusing processes. This is supposed to improve performance, but I want to make sure there aren't any memory leaks. Other than that, I went with default settings and opted for http/no authentication as the service will only ever be used by the local server itself. @JanBlaha

Comment: When you "enter....enter" through `jsreport configure` command. It creates jsreport.config.json with `templatingEngines.strategy=http-server` which will reuse processes.